# how to split date and filename of list elements and print only filename

Tags: python, split

I have set of files in a folder. I am reading the files in list and then splitting with `'_'`, but not getting correct result.

I tried below code:

```
    mylist = ['2014330_13252_Event.txt', '2014330_13252_Location.txt', 
    '2014330_13252_Place_name.txt', '2014330_13252_Place_add.txt', 
    '2014330_13252_Place_pin.txt']
    testlist = [i.split('_')[2] for i in mylist]
    print(testlist)
```

Output is:

```
testlist = ['Event.txt', 'Location.txt', 'Place', 'Place', 'Place']
```

I want output to be:

```
testlist = ['Event.txt', 'Location.txt', 'Place_name.txt', 'Place_add.txt', 'Place_pin.txt' ]
```

Comment: `i.split('_', 2)[2]`. If your filenames contain `_`, the filenames themselves contain is a valid split character. Simple workaround is to limit the number of parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module.

```
>>> mylist = ['2014330_13252_Event.txt', '2014330_13252_Location.txt', 
...     '2014330_13252_Place_name.txt', '2014330_13252_Place_add.txt', 
...     '2014330_13252_Place_pin.txt']
>>> 
>>> import re

>>> [re.match(r'(?:\d+_)+(.+)', i).group(1) for i in mylist]
['Event.txt', 'Location.txt', 'Place_name.txt', 'Place_add.txt', 'Place_pin.txt']
>>>
```

An explanation, if you care for one: `(?:\d+_)+` is a non-capturing group, `(?:)`, of one or more digits, `\d+`, followed by an underscore, `_`, and we make one or more of these matches (the trailing `+` sign). `(.+)` is a capturing group, `()`, of one or more non-line-break characters, `.+`. Put them together inside `re.match`, and we throw away one or more groups of (numbers followed by an underscore), then we match whatever is left and put it in a group, and finally spit that group out with `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
 mylist = ['2014330_13252_Event.txt', '2014330_13252_Location.txt', 
    '2014330_13252_Place_name.txt', '2014330_13252_Place_add.txt', 
    '2014330_13252_Place_pin.txt']

res = []
for i in mylist:
    res.append(i.split("_",2)[2])
print res
```

**Output**

```
['Event.txt', 'Location.txt', 'Place_name.txt', 'Place_add.txt', 'Place_pin.txt']
```